# Why this Dijkstra algorithm is working without using min heap?

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, queue, dijkstra

I implemented Dijkstra's algorithm using only a FIFO queue, still it passes all test cases in GFG. When will this code fail or if it works then why do we need to use a min heap?

```
vector <int> dijkstra(int V, vector<vector<int>> adj[], int S)
    {
        // adj [] = {{{1, 9}}, {{0, 9}}}

        vector<int> dist(V, INT_MAX);
        queue<pair<int, int>> pq;
        pq.push({0, S});
        while(!pq.empty()) {
            auto f = pq.front();
            pq.pop();
            int node = f.second;
            int d = f.first;
            if (d < dist[node]) 
            {
                dist[node] = d;
                for(auto i: adj[node]) {
                    pq.push({d + i[1], i[0]});
                }
            }
        }
        return dist;
    }
```

Comment: It will work as long as your input vector already is in a suitable order, and not otherwise. The word is 'algorithm', not 'algo' It is somebody's name. Don't abbreviate it.

Comment: This looks more like the Bellman-Ford algorithm implemented with a queue.

Comment: A FIFO queue works if all the weights are the same.  Then Dijkstra's algorithm is BFS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a FIFO instead of a min-heap will still give you the correct answer, but the time that your program will take to find that answer will be longer.

To be noticeable, you would need to provide a large graph as input.